# Incorporating Infographics from Power BI contest

Tags: typescript, powerbi

[Here](http://community.powerbi.com/t5/Best-Visual-Contest/Infographic-Easy-graphical-representations/cns-p/6694) is an amazing infographic visualization prepared by Andycross. I was planning to get this on my Power BI site.

After enabling developer tool, I have pasted this [infographic.ts](https://github.com/elastacloud/PowerBI-visuals/blob/infogram/src/Clients/Visuals/visuals/elastacloud/infograph.ts) in the available box, beneath it I pasted [infograph.capabilities.ts](https://github.com/elastacloud/PowerBI-visuals/blob/infogram/src/Clients/Visuals/capabilities/elastacloud/infograph.capabilities.ts) - next pressed `Compile + run`

I'm getting the following error

> "No 'export capabilities: VisualCapabilites' found inside the class
>   Infograph."

Please guide me where I'm wrong.

Note: I'm not much of a programmer but was able to get a few visuals from contest in the above manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to [this gist](https://gist.github.com/AndyCross/999842907fa92d0aff69) you can find something that you can copy and paste straight into dev tools.

Here's a little background on what is different from the contest entry that you linked to and why.

When I was developing the powerBI visuals, I was doing so before the [/devtools](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/devtools) toolset was available. The way to do it then (and a power-dev way of doing it still) is to clone the whole [visuals repo](http://github.com/microsoft/powerbi-visuals) and use Visual Studio to modify the source and then test it via the PowerBIPlayground app, that runs on your local machine. It's a really neat way of exploring the code and I've been doing that as my preferred way for a while now.

Anyway, in this case I'd made a light change to the way the data passed from PowerBI to the infogram visualization (via the Convert method) is augmented with additional data, that's simply not passed when you use the real powerBI environment (including [/devtools](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/devtools)). This is to add "general" data to the DataView implementation. This is not a good idea and would only ever 'work on my pc', never through PowerBI. Bad Andy.

The reason I was doing that was that I wanted the **ASSETS** to be configurable; by that I mean the image representations used in the infogram should be Apples and Pears, Men and Women, Hats and Mustaches or whatever else you want. You plug in *categoricals* through the PowerBI framework from whatever data source you want (i.e. 43% apples: 57% pears); I wanted to plug in *assets* too. However we're not there with the [/devtools](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/devtools) yet.

When you look at the [gist at line 78](https://gist.github.com/AndyCross/999842907fa92d0aff69#file-infograph-ts-L78) you can see two urls. You should change these to whatever you want the image representation to be. I've used two icons that I had to hand.

Other than that it should work.

**Another caveat** - the current implementation only supports categorical datasets and only selects the values for the first 2 rows. It's not particularly robust at doing this, so please let me know (create a new Stackoverflow and call me out) and I'll harden it up :)

Comment: Thanks Andy, I now have the icon in my Power BI site :). [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9u_K1HbgiEKYkZaR0Nyd19pbDA/view?usp=sharing) is the data I was trying to create an infograph on. But the visuals are still blank. Should I change the data way.

Comment: Hmm not sure the data looks like it should work. How does it look in terms of mappings/categories?

Comment: I've had a look at this in my sample; the categoricals get passed but not the values. This seems to be a problem with how I'm mapping my raw data through to the PowerBI visuals. My Visual expects it to come through the same way that the /devtools sends it through, but I'm struggling to reproduce that through PowerBI itself. 

I'm going to ask some chums over on the PowerBI team. Watch this space!

Comment: Thanks Andy :) eagerly awaiting

Comment: Hey @Vasim I've updated the gist with help from spatney (Sachin from the Microsoft PowerBI dev team). Turns out the 'capabilities' part of the Visual were wrong and aren't evaluated fully until you use it in the real canvas. 

anyway I've tried it with the latest gist and it works! 

Thanks to Sachin @ Microsoft too.

Comment: Finally! Success - thanks a lot. Now just awaiting to move to live mode (from preview mode) so that we can start using and sharing it. Thanks

Comment: I'm glad it works! I too am looking forward to seeing everything live. Can you send me a tweet @andyelastacloud with a screenshot of what you're doing with the visual? :)